# Can a user with limited access query from SOAP api?

Tags: api, soap-api, permissions, c#

So we have the exact same fields in the Sanbox and Production, however, when I run a select statement from the SOAP api, I am told a certain field is invalid. I confirmed it is not invalid.

The only difference is that in production, the user we are using for API access  has limited access. Could this cause such an error? Or should I be looking elsewhere for the cause?

Comment: Does the query work in your sandbox with an unrestricted user ? If yes, then it might be a field level security thing.

Comment: What do you mean the user has limited access in production? Do you mean that their license is restricted in the number of logins per month they can have? Or do you mean that they have limited access based on their object CRUD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects permission do matter a lot .If a user has no access to the object then we will run into this exception.

Please see that the user has atleast  read acess .